# Check password is weak,medium,strong

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
print ("Welcome to password generator!")
print ("We will check the level of your password for you!")
print ("There are 3 levels. Weak, Medium and Strong")
password = raw_input("Enter your password here: ")

weak = 'weak, add some extra characters, upper letters or numbers!'
medium = 'medium, you can add numbers to make it stronger!'
strong = 'strong, you are safe now!'

#Just making sure that password is ok
if len(password) > 12: 
    print ("Password must be longer than 6 and below 12!") 
elif len(password) < 6:
    print ("Password must be longer than 6 and below 12!") 


if password == password.lower or password == password.upper: #Check if password contain lower or upper letters
    print ('Your password is',weak)
if password.lower == password and password.upper == password: #Check if password contain lower and upper letters
    print ('Your password is',medium)
if password.lower == password and password.upper == password and any(str.isdigit(c) for c in password): #Check if password contain any number
    print ('Your password is',strong)

print ("\n")
if password == strong or password == medium or password == weak:
    print ("We are glad we help you, extra tip: Change password every 3-6 months!")
```

Problem is when i type password, for example "newpass" or "newpass1" i don't get any output. I expect to get "Your password is weak" or medium,...
But there's nothing.

Comment: Why password should be equal to one of the `weak` , `medium` or `strong` strings? you check if `newpass1` is equal to `weak` , `medium` or `strong` strings. I don't think that what you meant.

Comment: By the way. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29247821/edit

Comment: There are many basic mistakes, maybe it is better if you take a more thorough look to a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lower` and `upper` are methods, ie you need use `()` in order to actually call them.

For example, `if password == password.lower():`

```
password = 'PASS'
print(password.lower)
#  <built-in method lower of str object at 0x02386020>
print(password.lower())
#  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lower` and `upper` as methods:

```
if password == password.lower() or password == password.upper(): #Check if password contain lower or upper letters
    print ('Your password is',weak)
if password.lower() == password and password.upper() == password: #Check if password contain lower and upper letters
    print ('Your password is',medium)
if password.lower() == password and password.upper() == password and any(str.isdigit(c) for c in password): #Check if password contain any number
    print ('Your password is',strong)
```

Answer (score 0):

check lower or upper case like this

```
if password.islower() or password.isupper():
    print ('Your password is',weak)
if password.islower() == False and password.isupper() == False:
    if any(str.isdigit(c) for c in password):
        print ('Your password is',strong)
    else:
        print ('Your password is',medium)
```

Comment: This is not the same. The question is checking if the string has no case differences, not if it's only one case

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse this condition, used in the medium and strong

```
if password.lower() == password and password.upper() == password:
```

It checks if the password is all uppercase letters and all lowercase letters. Letters can't simultaneously be upper and lower case, therefore the code is never executed. Instead, you should use:

```
if password.lower() != password and password.upper() != password:
```

because this makes sure the password doesn't contain only upper on lower case letters

Comment: You could flip the first condition to an or. Why did you decide to flip the equality?

Comment: I think he is trying to check if the string is a mix of lower and upper case letters, making it an or would be true if the string was all upper or lower case @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

You should use `password.lower()` and `password.upper()` with the parenthesis, otherwise they will not return return a string when called, but another object, and the comparison

```
password == password.lower
```

and the others similar to it will always return `False`.